# save file to google cloud working directory

Tags: file, google-cloud-platform, deployment

Good morning. I am working in development with nodejs in local and I generate a .csv file
Once generated, I save it in the local system directory using library 'objects-to-csv';

Through the function:

```
     // New file csv
    const csv1 = new ObjectsToCsv(coordenadas);
    
    // Save to file:
    await csv1.toDisk('./coordenadas.csv');
   
  })()
```

If I deploy the application in google cloud, it works, however it reads the coordinates.csv file but does not rewrite it. There is some method without using storage?
Thank you

Comment: Which component are you using ? WHere is deployed you code? Does the .csv is provided with your code and then, you want to update it regularly? Does the rewritten fil need to be persistent?

Comment: Hello Guillaume, good cuestions: 1. Component: gcloud. 2. Deployed:App Engine 3. .csv is provided with me code, and update it regularly.  4. Don't need to be persistent.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the precision. Another question about the persistence of change. You change the file locally. But App Engine can scale automatically and create new instances. Each time a new instance is create, the CSV file from code is use, and not the latest updated by existing instances (a side effect is: a user performs a request, it use an already updated CSV. The same user, the next request, the next second, create a new instance and use a defaut CSV). Does it a problem?

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest, sorry for the delay in the response, but I have gone away for a few days of vacation.
The application performs the following task:
1. It presents three input fields:
latitude, longitude, and radius.

Comment: 2. Once the user has entered the data, the program calculates points in an area marked by the radius, at a distance between points of 3 km (according to the initial point (x) lat, lng entered by the user).

. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .
. . . x. . .
. . . . . . .
. . . . . . .

Comment: 3. The result of the calculations is presented in lat, lon coordinate format in a csv file and is automatically downloaded to the client.

Comment: To download the file I perform the following csv process:
a) I save the file in the root directory on the server.
b) From the server root directory, send the download to the client.
In development pc it works perfect.
When I deploy to google cloud, it only downloads the last file that was generated, so I think that the app engine performs as a photo of the system, packages it and starts it, but it cannot add files in that package, it must save them outside ( storage).
I am studying Cloud Storage FUSE.
Do you think it could be the solution? Thank you .

Comment: I think that I understood! Does my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use serverless application (App Engine, CLoud Run, Cloud functions) your code is packaged into a container. Thus, you can't write in it, only read. In each product, you still have an ["in-memory" file system in /tmp](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/using-temp-files)

So, use this directory to write the file and to serve it to your user. But, be careful, it's an in-memory file system. If you don't purge it (after the user download), you will reach the maximum allowed memory size and your instance will crash.

Comment: Wonderful! It works perfectly. Thank you very much.
If you visit Barcelona, ​​let me know, you are invited to a paella! Thanks again.

Comment: Sure!! I never visited Barcelona despite I went to Port Aventura!